# Rotate a line in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, cashapelayer, catransform3d

I have plus sign which i drawn using lines. Now i want to rotate these lines, so that it will look like a X sign. I tried rotating the lines but no way.

```
 self.shapeLayer1.transform = CATransform3DMakeRotation( (CGFloat) (GLKMathDegreesToRadians(-45)),0, 0, 0)




 self.shapeLayer2.transform = CATransform3DMakeRotation( (CGFloat) (GLKMathDegreesToRadians(-45)), 0, 0, 0)
```

You guys can see that, i put zeros in the x, y, z places.!! i tries different values.But colud not get the actual rotation. If somebody got any idea, Please share with me. Sometimes the lines move to another point and rotates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the x,y,z parameters define the axis of rotation.  Since we want to rotate around xy, your axis of rotation should be the z axis, or 0,0,1.

```
self.shapeLayer1.transform = CATransform3DMakeRotation( (CGFloat) (GLKMathDegreesToRadians(45)),0, 0, 1)

self.shapeLayer2.transform = CATransform3DMakeRotation( (CGFloat) (GLKMathDegreesToRadians(-45)), 0, 0, 1)
```

Regarding the issue you're having with rotation around a non-centerpoint of the line, if you're unable to redraw the line centred around 0,0,0, you can also use the following code to transform it to 0,0,0, rotate, then transform it back to where you need it:

```
CGFloat tx = 1.0,ty = 2.0,tz = 0;  // Modify these to the values you need
CATransform3D t = CATransform3DMakeTranslation (tx, ty, tz);
t = CATransform3DRotate(t,(CGFloat) (GLKMathDegreesToRadians(45)),0, 0, 1);
self.shapeLayer1.transform = CATransform3DTranslate(t,-tx,-ty,-tz);

CATransform3D t = CATransform3DMakeTranslation (tx, ty, tz);
t = CATransform3DRotate(t,(CGFloat) (GLKMathDegreesToRadians(-45)),0, 0, 1);
self.shapeLayer2.transform = CATransform3DTranslate(t,-tx,-ty,-tz);
```

Comment: Actually i want to rotate it from the center point. Now this line moves to another point and rotates it.

Comment: My guess is you're encountering a problem typical with OpenGL.  Rotation Matricies by default rotate around 0,0,0.  Basically you'll want to draw the line around 0,0,0, then transform it to where you want it.  Alternatively, you can do the transform first, then rotate, and transform back.  Order matters, but you can multiply the matrices by each other so the actual computation is actually only done once. You might want to read about Quaternions and how they work to demystify this a bit.

Comment: I dont get it. Got something else.?

Comment: Modified my answer to include rotation around an arbitrary point.

Comment: I tried it, but still it rotates from some other point, not from the center.

Comment: Your answer makes sense. Thank You.